# Comparing different sized arrays in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, compare

I need to compare two different arrays in Matlab. It's going to be used for a Yahtzee game. If I have an array that contains [1 2 3 4] and an array that contains [1 2 3 4 5], how do I check if the first array is contained within the second array. I just need to know a T/F result, not anything about which elements are missing, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ismember` will do it.  For example:

```
x = [1 2 3 4]
y = [1 2 3 4 5]
all(ismember(x,y))
```

You can also use `setdiff`.  For example:

```
isempty(setdiff(x,y))
```

Comment: thanks... idk why you have to take this obscure route to check strict equality though. :-(

Comment: For strict equality, use `isequal` or `isequalwithequalnans`.  This question was to check for set subset.

Answer (score 0):

another option,

```
all(intersect(x,y)==x)
```

but `ismember` is probably more efficient....